# how to make useEffect without initial render

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I just started learning javascript and react-redux, and I'm using useEffect to call POST method. So, I am wondering how to make it not send request to my backend whenever I open or refresh website

my HTTP Post looks like:

```
export const sendItemData = (items) => {
  return async () => {
    const sendRequest = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:51044/api/Items", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(items.Items),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
        credentials: "same-origin",
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Sending data failed!");
      }
    };

    try {
      await sendRequest();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

and my App.js looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import Items from "./components/Items ";
import { sendItemData } from "./store/items-actions";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const sendItems = useSelector((state) => state.items);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(sendItemData(sendItems));
  }, [sendItems, dispatch]);

  return <Items />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why do you use a useEffect for this case ? What's your idea behind this ?

Comment: What you want is to avoid running the code inside the useEffect the first time?

Comment: if you use use useEffect like   `useEffect(() => {   //effect  }, [ ])` , the empty square brackets depicts that the effect only run once and not on every render.

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier Well, as said, I'm learning how to code in react and few times I saw in courses that they use dispatch in useEffect (I'm assuming because they want to render whenever there are changes in dependencies) when calling HTTP Post. What do you suggest me to do? Should I just remove useEffect and use dispatch without it?

Comment: @ReynierRivero yes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is my way, tray it

```
export function MyComp(props) {
  const initial = useRef(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!initial.current) {
      // Yoyr code
    } else {
      // Mark for next times
      initial.current = false;
    }
  }, [args]);

  return (
    <YourContent />
  );
}
```